# How to write a linker script to place variables in specific segment in shared object?

Tags: c, linker, embedded-linux, cross-compiling

I have thousands of global variables of type struct My_Str_A and another thousands of global variables of type struct My_Str_B. They are partly initialized. By 'partly', I mean for everyone of the struct variable, not all the fields are initialized.
Currently all these variables are compiled and linked statically to main program.

The variables are defined in assembly, something like:

```
    .section .SEG_A,"a",%progbits
    .align 1
    .global global_conf_xxx
global_conf_xxx:
    .short   1
    .byte    0x20
    .byte    0
```

and

```
    .section .SEG_RAM_PTR,"a",%nobits
ram_xxx:
    .space   4
```

Linker script is something like:

```
SECTIONS
{
  PROVIDE (__executable_start = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x80000000)); . = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x80000000) + SIZEOF_HEADERS;
  .interp         : { *(.interp) }
  .note.gnu.build-id  : { *(.note.gnu.build-id) }
  .hash           : { *(.hash) }
  .gnu.hash       : { *(.gnu.hash) }
  .dynsym         : { *(.dynsym) }
  .dynstr         : { *(.dynstr) }
  .gnu.version    : { *(.gnu.version) }
  .gnu.version_d  : { *(.gnu.version_d) }
  .gnu.version_r  : { *(.gnu.version_r) }
    .text           :
    {
        *(.text.unlikely .text.*_unlikely .text.unlikely.*)
        *(.text.exit .text.exit.*)
        *(.text.startup .text.startup.*)
        *(.text.hot .text.hot.*)
        *(.text .stub .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)
        
        . = ALIGN(256);

        beginning_var_A = .;
        *(.SEG_A)
        ending_var_A = .;

        . = . + 64;

        . = ALIGN(4);
        beginning_var_B = .;
        *(.SEG_B)
        ending_var_A = .;
    }
      __bss_start = .;
      __bss_start__ = .;    
    .bss            :
    {
        *(.dynbss)
        *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*)
        *(COMMON)
        
        . = ALIGN(4);
        first_in_ram = .;
        *(.SEG_RAM_PTR)
    }
    _bss_end__ = .; __bss_end__ = .;
}
```

Now I want to pack all these variables to a shared object, and then dynamically linked to my main program. I need 2 linker scripts for shared object and main program seperately. Below is my requirements:

1. All the variables of type struct My_Str_A are placed in section named SEG_A, and all the variables of type struct My_Str_B are placed in section named SEG_B;
2. The 4 defined variables defined in the linker script of shared object denoting the beginning and end of SEG_A and SEG_B works properly in C source code;
3. The variable(first_in_ram) in bss section of shared object denoting the RAM address of user defined section SEG_RAM_PTR works properly in C source code.

I tried this way:
in libconf.lds:

```
SECTIONS
{
    .text           :
    {   
        . = ALIGN(256);

        beginning_var_A = .;
        *(.SEG_A)
        ending_var_A = .;

        . = . + 64;

        . = ALIGN(4);
        beginning_var_B = .;
        *(.SEG_B)
        ending_var_A = .;
    }
      __bss_start = .;
      __bss_start__ = .;    
    .bss            :
    {       
        . = ALIGN(4);
        first_in_ram = .;
        *(.SEG_RAM_PTR)
    }
    _bss_end__ = .; __bss_end__ = .;
}
```

in main.lds:

```
SECTIONS
{
  PROVIDE (__executable_start = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x80000000)); . = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x80000000) + SIZEOF_HEADERS;
  .interp         : { *(.interp) }
  .note.gnu.build-id  : { *(.note.gnu.build-id) }
  .hash           : { *(.hash) }
  .gnu.hash       : { *(.gnu.hash) }
  .dynsym         : { *(.dynsym) }
  .dynstr         : { *(.dynstr) }
  .gnu.version    : { *(.gnu.version) }
  .gnu.version_d  : { *(.gnu.version_d) }
  .gnu.version_r  : { *(.gnu.version_r) }
    .text           :
    {
        *(.text.unlikely .text.*_unlikely .text.unlikely.*)
        *(.text.exit .text.exit.*)
        *(.text.startup .text.startup.*)
        *(.text.hot .text.hot.*)
        *(.text .stub .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)
    }
      __bss_start = .;
      __bss_start__ = .;    
    .bss            :
    {
        *(.dynbss)
        *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*)
        *(COMMON)
    }
    _bss_end__ = .; __bss_end__ = .;
}
```

The result: some configuraton items work just as I wanted, but some other don't.
I checked the addresses of the workable and non-workable items, they are 0xf74a56c0 and 0x80845580 respectively. It seems the addr 0x80845580 goes beyond the scope of data segment, and belongs to text segment.

I assume the libconf.lds need to be changed someway. Can anyone help me on this?